# User input only once with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following line finds the positions where a word is found in a sentence:

```
print([i+1 for i in range(6) if a.split()[i] == b])
```

`a` is a string for the sentence (e.g. `"hello world this is a sentence"`"), and
`b` is the word to find in the sentence (e.g. `"world"`)

 The program works, but I want `b` to be user input, while keeping the program on a single line. Is this possible?
Thanks :)

**Edit:** What I meant was that the user should only be prompted once for an input. replacing `b` with `input()` will prompt multiple times if the word has been found more than once.

Comment: Does the whole program have to also be on one line, or only this action? (In other words, can helper functions be written?)

Comment: Is that a [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) question or is there any practical reason for the only-one-line requirement? It certainly doesn't promote clean, readable code.

Comment: BTW, your current code re-splits `a` on _every_ comparison, which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an embedded list-comprehension with a single `input()` item inside.

```
print([i+1 for b in [input()] for i in range(6) if a.split()[i] == b])
```

Example:

```
>>> print([i+1 for b in [input()] for i in range(6) if a.split()[i] == b])
world
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is:

```
print([i+1 for i in range(6) if a.split()[i] == input()])
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I meant - read the edit. Thanks, though @pp_

Answer (score 1):

Inbar Rose has shown how to put the `input()` call inside the list comprehension, if that's *really* what you want to do, but I advise against doing that. You should try to get (and possibly validate) user input in the outer part of your program structure, don't "bury" it inside the parts that perform the actual computations. Burying input calls deep in the code tends to make it less flexible and harder to debug.

Here's a more Pythonic way to do your list comprehension. It uses `enumerate` to produce an index of the current word while we're directly iterating over the word list, rather than using `range` and indirectly iterating over the word list via the indices.

Another benefit of this approach is that `a.split()` is executed only once, whereas in your code `a` is split into a list on *every* comparison.

```
a = "hello world this is a world sentence"
b = input("word: ")
print([i for i, u in enumerate(a.split(), 1) if u == b])
```

**Test output**, supplying `world` as the input

```
word: world
[2, 6]
```

Of course, the above code can be written on one line:

```
a = "hello world this is a world sentence"; b = input("word: "); print([i for i, u in enumerate(a.split(), 1) if u == b])
```

but the conventional Python style guide [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) says that you should generally avoid putting more than one statement on a line in a script. However, it can be convenient to combine multiple statements into one line when working in the interactive interpreter, but even then there are restrictions.